# When and how to update a cache

Tags: rest, caching, architecture

I have a service **A** and a service **B**.

The service **A** is a REST API that stores some relevant information, that the sevice **B** needs, in a database.

The service **B** handles a lot of traffic and is constantly consuming messages from a Kafka topic. Each message needs some information from the service **A**. But this information rarely changes, at most it changes a time per day.

So, in order to avoid hitting the REST API constantly for information that rarely changes, i'm going to implement a cache. (Not using a cache would give also the problem of querying the DB all the time). And the service **B** will hit the cache first, and if it doesn't have the required data it will only hit **A** once.

Here comes the question.

If the service **A** updates its information, i would need to update the cache **right away**.

What is the best way of doing this?

1) I can implement something in the REST API to let **B** notice that it needs to update his chache, but in terms of separation of concerns and encapsulation, isn't bad that **A** knows that **B** handles an internal cache? (I think it is)

2) I can implement a pool in **B** (and make B check if the info changed every X time) or get the cache updated every X time. But this way i have the risk of not getting the information updated **right away**.

3) Maybe a cache in **A** for this information? At least i avoid querying the DB, but not hitting the API :/

Is there a better way of handling this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a question of consistency guarantees and it is a core issue in distributed systems.

Your scenario contains three services: A, B and the database.
**If B must never ever under any circumstances use stale data**, then you have two options:

1. All reads will hit the database (no caching at A or B). Built in mechanisms at the database, such as the database's internal cache, disk cache and RAID mirroring, might relief some of the disk I/O bottleneck.
2. Cache the data at A (or B) and enforce strong consistency between the cache and the database, which means that every write would be done inside a distributed transaction between the database and the cache (or by using some other consensus protocol which provides strong consistency guarantees)

The first option requires no effort, and would work fine for a certain workload, but would become a serious bottleneck if the data ingress at B requires more throughput that the database can withhold.

The second option is quite complex to implement, would slow down data changes complicate the system and hurt its overall availability: if A goes down then data cannot be changed at the database; it a goes down amidst a transaction then the data won't be available for reading from the database (!)

**The good news is that most systems don't need such strong consistency guarantees, and they're OK with using stale data occasionally, under specific circumstances.**

If this is the case for your system, then there are several ways of invalidating the cache. Personally I'd go with Jose Martinez's suggestion to use a message queueing system, combined with the Publish/Subscribe pattern: service B would publish a "data changed" message to the pub/sub (the message would include information as to what data item changed exactly), service A would be a subscriber processing "data changed" messages and invalidating its cache as they arrive.

Additional points:

Caching inside B might seem like it can provide strong consistency at first, but truth is you might need to scale B so you'll have multiple instances of B, each with its own cache that needs be invalidated and synchronized.

You may use a whole other service for holding the cached data (Redis, Memcached etc.), which would allow you to split he responsibilities over the cached data (B could invalidate it and A could be reading from it directly), but it won't change the essence of the consistency dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a third bullet point to @CapnSchwenk's answer...

3. Have A submit all changes to a message queue, like Rabbit MQ.  The message queue can handle persistence (in case B is down), and publisher design model implementation.  The queue can also contain the new data so that B need not have to query A for the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this statement: "If the service A updates its information, i would need to update the cache right away", then your 2 choices in my experience would be some form of distributed cache:

1. Have service A provide a listener mechanism that Service B can subscribe to, to invalidate its own internal cache when data changes;
2. Implement a distributed caching layer such as ehcache or memcache that both Service A and B are aware of; when Service A updates it writes the new value into the cache and all subscribers are automatically updated

Hope that helps!